# Vaex expression to select all rows

Tags: python, numpy, vaex

In Vaex, what expression can be used as a filter to select all rows? I wish to create a filter as a variable and pass that to a function.

```
filter = True
if x > 5:
 filter = y > 20
df['new_col'] = filter & z < 10
```

My wish is that if x <= 5 it will ignore the filter (thus I'm trying to use True as a value). Doing it this way gives the error `'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` What expression will select all rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly a simple trick to  "disable" all filters (i.e. get all rows back) is to do something like

```
df[True | filter]
```

Making the condition always True, so nothing is filtered out.